# Input field for Shipping Method in Admin Order Create

Tags: magento2

When we create admin order in Shipping Method, I would like to have an input field for shipping method similar to the payment methods like Purchase Order Number in the Purchase Order. (Check the image below)

[image]
[image]

Comment: you want to add pickup date field in admin side, when Order creating ?

Comment: Yes, i want to add store selection and pickup date, but not getting any option to add them.

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/bippo/customshippingrate-magento) in magento 2?

Comment: I want to add account no field in custom shipping method. @PurushotamSharma